# Pass jQuery change as a paramater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of places in my application where I need to execute JS function and also bind it to some jquery event like "change" or "click". For refactoring purposes I'd like to create a generic function that should help me accomplish this. Here are my original thoughts:

```
function execute_and_track(trackEvent, action) {
    action();
    trackEvent(function () {
        action();
    });
}
```

And I thought to use it like this:

```
execute_and_track($("#ddl_Test").change, function () {
    if ($("#ddl_Test").val().toUpperCase() == "OTHER") {
        document.getElementById("txt_Test").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("txt_Test").style.display = "none";
        $("#txt_Test").val("");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'on'. It looks like I am not able to pass jquery change as a parameter. Can anybody help me to fix this logic or suggest another way of creating generic function for such refactoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, I would change approach.

Try this new one (as jquery plugin)

```
$.fn.execute_and_track = function(eventName, func) {
    this.each(function() {
        func.call(this); // fix the scope
        $(this).on(eventName,func);
    });
    return this;
}

$("#ddl_Test").execute_and_track('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val().toUpperCase() == "OTHER") {
        this.style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        this.style.display = "none";
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's a good idea to use jquery plugin here. It works fine. Thanks.